# How to use SpEL in Spring application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

Is it possible to use SpEL expressions in spring `application.properties`?

My goal is to include the hostname in a property. The property is read by a framework that I have no control of, that's why I have to directly add the hostname into that property.

The following example does of course not work, but shows my intention:

```
spring.application.name=Some prefix - http://#{T(java.net.InetAddress).localHost.canonicalHostName}
```

Comment: You could add an environment post processor to set the property programmatically on startup

Comment: Could you add an example on how to achieve that?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-environmentpostprocessor  similar idea, except you'd just get the property then set your `spring.application.name` property and set the precedence if you want your property to to highest.